# Ajax - Modal - Passing Variable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I know this has been asked a lot but after looking up for this for like 6 hours I can say I've tried everything that with my current knowledge (which isn't much) I can understand so I decided to come here and ask for help from the pros :).

This button is also inside korisnik.php

```
<button href="#myModal1" type="submit" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-id="<?php print $row['kime']?>" class="open-myModal1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"/></button>
```

This up top is a button that when clicked opens a modal and should pass a value to it, but it doesn't. After looking through a lot of posts on the net I found out easiest way is to send the variable back through AJAX so I used this:

This is located in bottom part of korisnik.php

```
$(document).on("click", ".open-myModal1", function () 
{
    var kime = $(this).data('id');
    $(".modal-body #kime").val( kime );
    $.post('korisnik.php', { 'kime': kime });
});
```

Using `$kime = $_POST['kime']; print $kime;` in korisnici.php doesn't show the value at all but using `<input type="text" name="kime" id="kime" value=""/>` does. Problem with the one that works is that I still don't have the value needed inside a variable and can't use it to make a query based on the sent value.

So my question is:

How to make this work with ajax so I can get the value with $_POST['kime']?

or

How can I save the value inside the input field inside a variable?

I hope I've been clear enough with my request. Either one of those works since I get what I want and that is a value saved inside a variable I can use for other things.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: This is modal Code inside korisnik.php

```
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal1">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <center><h4 class="modal-title">EDIT KORISNIKA</h4></center>
                    </div><!-- end header -->
                    <hr/>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <!--<input type="text" name="kime" id="kime" value=""/>-->
                        <input type='text' name='kime' id='kime' value=''/>
                        <form class="form-horizontal" action='korisnik.php' method="post">
                        <?php
                        $kime = $_POST['kime'];
                        $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM korisnik WHERE kime = :kime");             
                        $query-> execute(array(':kime' => $kime ));
                        $result = $query->fetch();
                        ?>
                            <table class="table table-striped"> 
                                <tr><th style="vertical-align:middle"><center>Korisničko Ime</center></th><td><input readonly class="form-control"  name="username" value="<?php print $result['kime'] ?>"id="username" type="text"></td></tr>
                                <tr><th style="vertical-align:middle"><center>Ime</center></th><td><input class="form-control" onkeydown="ime(this)" onkeyup="ime(this)" onblur="ime(this)" onclick="ime(this)"  name="name" id="name" value="<?php print $result['ime'] ?>"  type="text"></td></tr>
                                <tr><th style="vertical-align:middle"><center>Prezime</center></th><td><input class="form-control" onkeydown="ime(this)" onkeyup="ime(this)" onblur="ime(this)" onclick="ime(this)" name="surname" id="surname" value="<?php print $result['prezime'] ?>" type="text"></td></tr>
                                <tr><th style="vertical-align:middle"><center>E-Mail</center></th><td><input class="form-control" name="email" id="email" onkeydown="emailk(this)" onkeyup="emailk(this)" onblur="emailk(this)" onclick="emailk(this)" value="<?php print $result['email'] ?>" type="email"></td></tr>
                                <tr><th style="vertical-align:middle"><center>Kredit</center></th><td><input class="form-control" name="kredit" id="kredit" onkeydown="alpha(this)" onkeyup="alpha(this)" onblur="alpha(this)" onclick="alpha(this)" value="<?php print $result['kredit'] ?>" type="number"></td></tr>
                            </table>
                    </div><!-- end body-->
                    <hr/>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-left" name="editk" value="Spremi Promjene" />
                        </form>         
                        <button class="btn btn-default pull-right" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Odustani</button>
                    </div><!-- end footer -->
                </div><!-- end modal-content -->
            </div><!-- end modal-dialog -->
        </div><!-- end modal -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in the end after hours of what seemed endless searching and reading I found the solution to this. Instead of sending a variable to modal and doing query inside modal I did query before modal and sent all the values I needed like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).on("click", ".open-myModal1", function () 
    {

      var kime = $(this).data('id');
      var ime = $(this).data('ime');
      var prezime = $(this).data('prezime');
      var email = $(this).data('email');
      var kredit = $(this).data('kredit');

      $(".modal-body #username").val( kime );
      $(".modal-body #name").val( ime );
      $(".modal-body #surname").val( prezime );
      $(".modal-body #email").val( email );
      $(".modal-body #kredit").val( kredit );
    });
    </script>
```

and the button I used to open modal was like this.

```
<button href="#myModal1" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-id="<?php print $row['kime']?>" data-ime="<?php print $row['ime']?>" data-prezime="<?php print $row['prezime']?>" data-email="<?php print $row['email']?>" data-kredit="<?php print $row['kredit']?>" class="open-myModal1"></button>
```

Modal code:

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal1">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <center><h4 class="modal-title">EDIT KORISNIKA</h4></center>
                </div><!-- end header -->
                <hr/>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" action='korisnik.php' method="post">
                        <table class="table table-striped"> 
                            <tr><th style="vertical-align:middle"><center>Korisničko Ime</center></th><td><input readonly class="form-control"  name="username" value=""id="username" type="text"></td></tr>
                            <tr><th style="vertical-align:middle"><center>Ime</center></th><td><input class="form-control" onkeydown="ime(this)" onkeyup="ime(this)" onblur="ime(this)" onclick="ime(this)"  name="name" id="name" value=""  type="text"></td></tr>
                            <tr><th style="vertical-align:middle"><center>Prezime</center></th><td><input class="form-control" onkeydown="ime(this)" onkeyup="ime(this)" onblur="ime(this)" onclick="ime(this)" name="surname" id="surname" value="" type="text"></td></tr>
                            <tr><th style="vertical-align:middle"><center>E-Mail</center></th><td><input class="form-control" name="email" id="email" onkeydown="emailk(this)" onkeyup="emailk(this)" onblur="emailk(this)" onclick="emailk(this)" value="" type="email"></td></tr>
                            <tr><th style="vertical-align:middle"><center>Kredit</center></th><td><input class="form-control" name="kredit" id="kredit" onkeydown="alpha(this)" onkeyup="alpha(this)" onblur="alpha(this)" onclick="alpha(this)" value="" type="number"></td></tr>
                        </table>
                </div><!-- end body-->
                <hr/>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-left" name="editk" value="Spremi Promjene" />
                    </form>         
                    <button class="btn btn-default pull-right" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Odustani</button>
                </div><!-- end footer -->
            </div><!-- end modal-content -->
        </div><!-- end modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- end modal -->
```

Thanks to all who tried to help! Till next time!

Answer (score 0):

I think you mistake in syntax. You should call it like this:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url:  "korisnik.php",
data: 
  {
     kime: kime
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing curly brace on your on click function.

```
$.post('korisnik.php', { 'kime': kime });
```

Above post should also work.

Retrieve it in PHP as follow:

```
$kime = $_POST['kime'];
```

Comment: I already fixed the missing curly brace but forgot to edit it here. Tried also using this you posted instead of ajax but it doesn't work. Could the problem be inside the korisnik.php? Maybe the position of the code is the problem. When I click on the button the modal window opens but the variable isn't passed... Inside modal I put `$kime = $_POST['kime']; print $kime;` but it doesnt print it inside the modal. I would post whole korisnik.php but it's pretty huge. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: If you are using Chrome as your browser, you can check your network tab in inspector to see if the post is actually sending the correct data to your php file.

Comment: Tried what you said and when I clicked on the button I get this in the network tab. http://i61.tinypic.com/120h0rn.png I supposed that means the value gets passed via POST. So why the hell can't I pick up the variable with $_POST?

Comment: When you click into it, you will see a headers tab. Read through it to see if the post value is in there. It will be under "Request Headers".  If it is there, then something is wrong on the php side.

Comment: http://i60.tinypic.com/1g5f8i.png According to this the variable is there with the value it should have.

Comment: Then the problem lies on the PHP side.

Comment: Thanks for helping. So what happens first when I click on the button? Does the script run and send the value or does the modal window open first?